# Getting 404 page when creating multiple pages in Next.js 13.4

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

Since Next.js 13.4.2 I can't create multiple Pages in Next.js.

I tried to recreate a new Next.js app again and added pages to it with simple codes just to see if it works.

```
//page2.js

export default function Page2() {

    return(

        <>

            <h1>Test</h1>

        </>

    )

}
```

But it still didn't work. It always shows me the 404 page. I already have checked the link `http://localhost:3000/page`

The file structure

```
...

|-app

|--globals.css

|--layout.js

|--page.js

|--page.module.css

|--page2.js //not working

...
```

Comment: You can check here how it works now : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts
If you want a route `/page` you need to create a folder `page` in the folder `app` with a file `page.js` in it

Comment: So does that mean, now instead of index.js we write page.js in Next.   Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the app router you need to follow Next.js file convention, that is the folders determine the route path and a special file `page.js|ts` makes a certain path publicly accesible. Take for example the following folder structure:

```
app/
  page.js -> http://localhost:3000/
  foo/
    page.js -> http://localhost:3000/foo
    bar/
      page.js -> http://localhost:3000/foo/bar
    test/
      page.js -> http://localhost:3000/foo/test
```

You can read more in the routing guide https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing

Comment: tried this but not working for me